Roadmap to develop an application on top of CiviCRM for my organization
I want to build a custom CRM for my organization to manage Sales and Marketing.
I want to build it on top of CiviCRM, but change the whole UI, and display my organization name in place of CiviCRM everywhere in whole application and build custom modules as well.
I am very new to this CRM, please someone help me on how to do this. I have been doing R&D for 3-4 days now but haven't really learned anything yet. Also, there is no content available to learn this thing. Please help me how to develop a new application using the existing structure of CiviCRM, really need you help guys.

"there is no content available to learn this thing". what do you mean. have you visited https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/ and https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest

also pls clean up your Tags as they are not v helpful imo.
